# How to retrieve the PR number in nodejs github probot listening on `pull_request` event

Tags: node.js, typescript, github-api, probot

I have created a `GitHub probot` app using `nodejs` and `typescript`. I am listening on `pull_request` event. How do I retrieve `pr_number` from the probot `context` object?

following is the code in `intex.ts`

```
export = (app: Application) => {
  app.on('pull_request', async (context) => {

  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field that you're interested in is `context.payload` inside the callback:

```
export = (app: Application) => {
  app.on('pull_request', async (context) => {
    const payload = context.payload
    // ...
  })
}
```

This matches the payloads listed in the GitHub Webhook Events page: https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#events

You're interested in the `pull_request` payload which can be found here: https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent

And `pull_request.number` is your relevant piece of information you need:

```
export = (app: Application) => {
  app.on('pull_request', async (context) => {
    const payload = context.payload
    const number = payload.pull_request.number
  })
}
```